# When view model is loaded, dropdownboxes not populated

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using C# ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework, trying to create a web application that doesn't really need to be on more than one 'page', using partial views and dialogs for everything.

The index page displays a table, and there are jquery buttons that link to dialogs, which contain partial views for doing stuff with.

I'm currently dealing with the partial view responsible for adding and editing entities in the table. It adds them fine, and the partial works great for that, but when I try to load an object into the viewmodel, things go awry. The entity itself is entirely complete, no worries there, but not all the information is loaded in the partial view, and some of it is in the wrong format. Specifically,

[image: The edit dialog which is causing issues]

All those dropdownboxes should be filled. They are populated, just not with the right value. Also, there is code in the viewmodel that should stop the date from appearing as it does;

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Date Requested")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
public System.DateTime DateRequested { get; set; }
```

The controller action that presents the partial view is as such;

```
public ActionResult _advisoryRequestForm(string id = "")
{
    ViewBag.datepickeruid = Guid.NewGuid();
    setViewBagNewAR();

    if (id.Equals(""))
        return PartialView();
    BCRTAdvisoryRequest request = new AdvisoryRequestsLogic().getAdvisoryRequestByID(Convert.ToInt32(id));      
    return PartialView(request);
}
```

The ajax call;

```
$(".editRequest").button().on("click", function () {        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/_advisoryRequestForm',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "&id="+this.id,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $('#ardialog-form').html(response);
                requestForm = $('#ardialog-form').find('#advisoryRequestForm');
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(requestForm);
                editRequestDialog.dialog("open");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); }
    });
});
```

The partial view returned;

```
@model EH.BCRT.AdvisoryRequests.Model.BCRTAdvisoryRequest

<link href="@Url.Content("/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" />

<form id="advisoryRequestForm">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>BCRTAdvisoryRequest</legend>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="h-double">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RequestTypeID)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestTypeID)<br />
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RequestTypeID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RequestTypeID, "", null)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateRequested)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateRequested)<br />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateRequested, new { @class = "datepickerfield", id = ViewBag.datepickeruid })
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteName)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteName)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceCategoryID)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceCategoryID)<br />
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceCategoryID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ServiceCategoryID, "", null)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)<br />
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { style = "width:95%;min-height:80px;" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="h-double">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestedBy)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestedBy)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestedBy)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobTitle)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobTitle)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobTitle)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocalOfficeOrTeam)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocalOfficeOrTeam)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocalOfficeOrTeam)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteVisit)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteVisit)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteVisit)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusID)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusID)<br />
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StatusID, "", null)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConsultantRetained)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConsultantRetained)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConsultantRetained)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="h-single">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments)<br />
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, new { style = "width:95%;min-height:80px;" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
 }
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepickerfield').each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong with the dropdowns and the date field?

**setViewBagNewAR()**

```
private void setViewBagNewAR()
{
    var ARLogic = new AdvisoryRequestsLogic();
    ViewBag.StatusID = ARLogic.getRequestStatuses();
    ViewBag.RequestTypeID = ARLogic.getRequestTypes();
    ViewBag.ServiceCategoryID = ARLogic.getServiceCategories();
}
```

Comment: Can you add what's going on in `setViewBagNewAR`?  And if you open dev tools if you manually run your `$('.datepickerfield)...` code does it do what you expect?

Comment: What's in: setViewBagNewAR() ?

Comment: Lol, I had that in the example but took it out, setViewBagNewAR() simply contains a bunch of lists from the database, which are used to give the dropdownlists a list of values from which to choose from. I'll add it. Also yes, the datepicker stuff does as it should by my eye.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using a true ViewModel to pass to your views, not just a domain/data model. (and put everything in it, as opposed to some things in ViewBag) I can go into more detail once you show setViewBag

Comment: What type does getRequestStatuses() return?

Comment: It returns SelectList

Comment: Does the SelectList it returns have the dataValueField, and dataTextField's set? (new SelectList(items, "Id", "Val")) If not it will display the items' type in the DDL. (I'm not sure if that is the symptom you are seeing or not.)

Comment: Yes, it does. All I did was move the entity framework generated code into a method so I could call it using my own BLL class and not have to write it out in every partial view. The selectlist is formatted fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectLists placed in the ViewBag should be named differently than all of your model properties.

For example, you can rewrite the controller for status id to:

```
    ViewBag.StatID = ARLogic.getRequestStatuses();
```

Then, change the DropDownlistFor in your View to

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusID, (SelectList)ViewBag.StatID, "", null)
```

As for the date format, there is an ApplyFormatInEditMode property which will apply format to dates in an EditorFor.

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: I can't tell you for sure whether the last point will work or not until Monday. As for your first point, why?

Comment: It seems like a strange behavior, but DropDownlistFor actually looks at the ViewBag for a property matching the for property name before looking at the actual model property value. For this reason, it is better to define a viewmodel with the selectlist than passing it through the viewbag. You can see this behavior by naming your selectlist differently than your model property, and adding a value to the viewbag matching one of the values in your selectlist. No value was selected in your list because it was looking for an item with a value matching the IEnumerable<SelectListItem>.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I actually found that out whilst travelling SO earlier, do you know why the behaviour is different for DropDownListFor and DropDownList? I reverted to simply using DropDownList as it was an easier solution to my problem, but it seems odd to me to have these little quirks.

Comment: I did try to edit your last comment into the answer so it would be harder for people to miss it, but the peer review monkeys weren't having it, so I'll just accept the answer anyway.